# Complexity of checking if AB intersects C

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, gr.group-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be subsets of a nonabelian group $G$,
and assume we know the structure of $G$ "fairly well"
(e.g., $G = S_n$ or $A_n$).
Assume that group operations take $O(1)$ time.

> Is it possible to check whether $AB \cap C \ne \emptyset$ in $o(|A| |B| + |C|)$ time
> (ideally quasilinear)?

#### Motivation:

A quasilinear time algorithm would produce
a roughly $O(|G|^{1/3})$ time algorithm for shortest paths in certain Cayley graphs
([if they are expanders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341471/computing-shortest-paths-in-cayley-graphs)).

Comment: If $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be *any subset* of $G$, why should $G$ being a group help? Is something known about the abelian case?

Comment: It's quite possible that it doesn't.  The abelian case where $|A|,|B| = \Theta(|G|)$ can be solved via Fourier transform, but I don't know how to do small subsets.